# live streaming in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, audioformat, live-streaming

Will the ALAC format support live streaming in iPhone ? the ALAC audio recording format is streamed to Server machine? so will i be able to play the audio chunk data, does ALAC format support?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "Apple Lossless" audio...

I don't see why it wouldn't, but I don't know the details. You'll probably need to embed it in a transport stream instead of a MPEG 4 container (but then, I don't know how the HTTP live streaming works either).

I don't think streaming lossless audio is sensible, though.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming lossless audio is possible, we have flac streaming using icecast and it works beautifully.  However, we are not using HTTP Live Stream (HLS) to do it.  We stream flac from the source generator to a number of servers and they create HLS's from there.

It is technically possible to mux alac into mpegts (ffmpeg can do this) as well as play it back (using ffmpeg), but there isn't a format identifier for other clients.  Adding this feature to HLS will be as easy as calling/writing Apple and asking them to add ALAC to this list:

http://www.smpte-ra.org/mpegreg/mpegreg.html

and update their products accordingly.  If you've purchased an Apple product less than 90 days ago, or you have AppleCare: give them a call.  They *have* to work on the issue for you if you are covered.  The more requests that get elevated to their engineers, the more likely they are to add support for alac in HLS.